# Ran 0 tests in 0.000s when using exec() unit test file in python

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a python program mid.py :

```
def mid(a, b):
    if a == 0:
        print(b)
        r = b
        r = r + 1
        return r
    while b != 0:
        if a > b:
            a = a - b
        else:
            b = b - a
    print(a)
    r = a
    return r
```

I wrote unit test for this in unitTest1.py:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
from Data.mid import mid

import unittest


class TestSum(unittest.TestCase):
    currentResult = None  # holds last result object passed to run method


    def run(self, result=None):
        self.currentResult = result  # remember result for use in tearDown
        unittest.TestCase.run(self, result)  # call superclass run method


    def test_sum_1(self):
        self.assertEqual(mid(3, 2), 1, "Should be 2")
    def test_sum_2(self):
        self.assertEqual(mid(5, 5), 5, "Should be 5")
    def test_sum_3(self):
        self.assertEqual(mid(3, 3), 3, "Should be 3")
    def test_sum_4(self):
        self.assertEqual(mid(5, 3), 1, "Should be 4")
    def test_sum_5(self):
        self.assertEqual(mid(2, 4), 2, "Should be 2")
    def test_sum(self):
        self.assertEqual(mid(0, 2), 2, "Should be 2")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(exit=False)
```

after that I use exec() to run unitTest1.py in the other file (Fitness.py) by getting the context of unitTest1.py at path D:\docu\KL\Data\unitTest1.py and excute by exec() method :

```
import sys
import ast
import astor
sys.path.append('..')
from FaultLocalization.Tracer import Tracer
from FaultLocalization.DataReader import DataReader
from AstTree.AstHelper import AstHelper
class Fitness:
    def FitnessFunction(self):
        dT = DataReader()
        ctx = dT.getContextFileWithPath("D:\\docu\\KL\\Data\\unitTest1.py")
        exec (ctx)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = Fitness()
    f.FitnessFunction()
```

It returns "Ran 0 tests in 0.000s" . Why is that? When I put exec() method in main function it works fine but I really want to use FitnessFunction like above. Any other way to handle it?

Comment: Why does the error message for two of your test cases indicate an expected value *other* than the one you are testing against? E.g., `assertEqual(..., 1, "Should be 2")`. If you are checking if the return value is 1, why do you say "should be 2"?

Comment: I change the value of the test cases but forget to change "Should be ..." =)) Does this affect the program? @chepner